# QLineEdit can't get anything

Tags: python, pyqt

i using pyqt develop a dialog, and a LineEidt
some like below, but i can't get anything from lineEdit1:

```
lineEdit1 = QtGui.QLineEdit()
lineEdit1.setEchoMode(2)
passWord = lineEdit1.text()
```

Comment: Are you watching console output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lineEdit1 = QtGui.QLineEdit()
lineEdit1.setEchoMode(2)
passWord = lineEdit1.text()
```

of course you can't get anything, because when `lineEdit1.text()` is executed, I believe there is no characters input into `lineEdit1`.
You should call `passWord = lineEdit1.text()`  by some action when the input is over, for example, click a button.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute your code on the `editingFinished()` signal of QLineEdit. It will be executed when the QLineEdit loses focus.